# Java BlockingQueue produces/consumes not properly

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve Twitter messages using the TwitterAPI, process them and store them in a database. I am using Producer/Consumer BlockingQueue where the elements act as follows:

- Producer : retrieves the Twitter messages using the TwitterAPI and stores it in a BlockingQueue.
- Consumer : takes an element from the queue, processes it and stores it in a database.

Here is the Main class:

```
    // Creating shared object
    BlockingQueue<TwitterMessage> sharedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<TwitterMessage>(1);

    // Creating Producer and Consumer Thread
    Thread prodThread = new Thread(new TwitterStreamProducer(sharedQueue));
    Thread consThread = new Thread(new TwitterStreamConsumer(sharedQueue));

    // Starting producer and Consumer thread
    prodThread.start();
    consThread.start();
```

The producer processes the TwitterAPI response and adds the object to the queue.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            message = extractData(); // extract data from TwitterAPI response and return TwitterMessage object
            sharedQueue.put(message);

            System.out.println("Produced: " + message.getTwitterMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TwitterStreamProducer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer does as follows:

```
private final BlockingQueue<TwitterMessage> sharedQueue;
private TwitterProcessor twitterProcessor;
private TwitterMessage twitterMessage;

public TwitterStreamConsumer(BlockingQueue<TwitterMessage> sharedQueue) {
    this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    twitterProcessor = new TwitterProcessor();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            twitterMessage = this.twitterProcessor.process(sharedQueue.take());
            if (twitterMessage.getTwitterMessage().length() > 1) {
                System.out.printf("Consumed: %s\n", twitterMessage.getTwitterMessage());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TwitterStreamConsumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As I would expect to see is the following:

```
Produced: …twittermessage1… 
Consumed: …twittermessage1… 
Produced: …twittermessage2… 
Consumed: …twittermessage2… 
Produced: …twittermessage3… 
Consumed: …twittermessage3…
...
```

However, the result I'm getting is the following:

```
Produced: …twittermessage1…
Produced: …twittermessage2…  <= problem
Consumed: …twittermessage1…
Produced: …twittermessage3…
Consumed: …twittermessage3…
Consumed: …twittermessage3…  <= problem
Produced: …twittermessage4…  <= problem
Produced: …twittermessage5…
Consumed: …twittermessage5…
```

As you can see, sometimes there is an overlap between Producer and Consumer where the Producer produces messages too many that are not consumed. Also sometimes a message gets consumed twice (or sometimes even more than twice)

**EDIT1**
Here is what is printed out on the console:

```
Produced: @1StevenGeorgiou thanks for the follow #ff
Processed: follow
Produced: @nmagliozzi6 @_PatrickKealy_ but of course!!!!!
Produced: @taylorgaglia Thanks Tayl  miss you tooo
Processed: tayl miss
Produced: Hate this who to follow tab in #twitter it's shows the most pathetic people you know. Accidently added one I had to act fast to unfollow
Processed: hate follow tabshow pathet peopl accid ad act fast unfollow
```

**EDIT2**
As John Vint suggested to print out the 'System.identityHashCode(sharedQueue.take())' I get the following:

```
Produced: …
Consumed: 1206857787
Produced: …
Consumed: 1206857787
…
```

Can someone help me out here how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: And why is this a problem exactly?

Comment: Because I do not want my application to process something twice or lose twitter messages retrieved from the API… for example: 'twittermessage2' is produced but never consumed. Also 'twittermessage3' gets consumed twice.

Comment: Why are you using thread? if you want to produce after that consume and again produce after that consume.

Comment: How is your counter generated?

Comment: Well, is seems that 'twittermessage2' is being overwritten by 'twittermessage3' before it is consumed.  I suspect that omitting the producer code may have been a mistake:)

Comment: It's hard to tell whether what you think to see is really happening. For example, the message `Produced message2` might be printed by the producer, **after** the consumer has taken message 1 out of the queue, but **before** he printed his output. Some additional synchronization could help to rule this one out (ONLY to verify whether this is the case or not!)

Comment: Martin James is probably correct here about an errant producer.

Comment: I added the Producer code.

Comment: Does extractData() return a new object on each call?

Comment: Ow, could this happen because my System.out.println() in the Producer is AFTER adding it to the queue?

Comment: There is that, yes, but not only, see my answer

Comment: Don't think so, unless the consumer mutates it, which it appears it does not.

Comment: @MartinJames yes extractData() returns a new object on each call. Is this bad practice?

Comment: What would be also needed is the code of `extractData()` here

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 I don't see anything really telling with your code.  If you can create a runnable test that reproduces it that would help.

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 Also, consider printing the `System.identityHashCode(sharedQueue.take())` as I am certain you shouldn't be consuming the same message twice.

Comment: I would bet that 'twittermessage2' was properly consumed, but it was not printed because the if(condition) that guards the print statement was false.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin, I commented out the if statement but still the problem occurs

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 Is that the identity hash of `sharedQueue.take()` or the `twitterProcessor.process(..)`

Comment: @JohnVint it is of `sharedQueue.take()`

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 As you can imagine there isn't much we can tell you at this point.  If you can put some code together that I can run without any dependencies we can get a better idea.  What you are seeing is, in my opinion, a programming error on your part, though what you are showing us should work fine, assuming `sharedQueue.put` is receiving new objects each time.

Comment: 'Is this bad practice? ' no, it's essential practice when communicating objects between threads:)

Comment: @JohnVint is there a way I can send you my Java project? I think this will be easier/faster for both of us.

Comment: Push it to github if you have one and link to it.  That would be easiest

Comment: @JohnVint sorry but I do not have git, also since the project contains my API keys etc, I don't feel comfortable by sharing it here to the public.

Comment: Ok, then push to http://pastebin.com/ for the code you wrote, don't need keys or anything like that

Comment: I have found the culprit. It was a stupid mistake on my side. 'extractData()' creates and returns a new object, however, in the body I call another method that did NOT return a new object. After altering my code such that those methods DO return a new object, and now the producer produces more than one message but the consumer now consumes them all and only once. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

The code is behaving as it should: the order of execution with threads is undefined. Therefore it is very possible and likely that the producers produce more than one message before the previous one is processed. This is even a desirable feature, as it allows to have several threads handling the fetching (producers), which will take some time as of blocking, and have less or even a single consumer actually processing those intermediate results.

But in your code you are violating this basic rule for Producers/Consumers, which is that there needs to be a difference in relationship for them. As you currently have a producer/consumer pair for each message, the pattern used is only slowing down things. You should either increase the number of fetchers (and accept that the processing is asynchronously), or - if you don't want the asynchronous processing - remove the pattern altogether and have the "consumers" fetch the message on their own.

Edit: If you use a concurrent queue like the [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) your problem should be solved.
Also have a look into the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class, which simplifies threading with Runnables a lot.

Comment: How the processing is done does not really matter, I just don't want it to produce messages that are not being consumed. Also i don't want it to be consumed twice. That's practically the only problem because I do not want my database to be populated with the same message more than once.

Comment: Sorry... totally forgot about answering your actual question. ;) Edited that in.

Comment: Having one producer and one consumer connected with a BlockingQueue is not unusual or undesirable.  It is in the nature of network and DB I/O that latency and workload vary considerably with time, and introducing the 'slack' of the queue between them improves the performance during short-term overloads that would otherwise generate network blocking and reduced throughput.

Comment: I agree that IO blocking is an issue that needs to be taken into account, however if in a 1:1 relationship the reader (producer) would actually immediately process (consume) the message, you would have the same result, just without the overhead of the pattern. Therefore simpler, cleaner and faster code, while still avoiding all blocking issues.

Comment: The result might be simpler and cleaner. I have big problems with 'faster' though, as a general statement. In the best-case scenario, where the producer and consumer both have to put in just enough CPU work to use up one core at the average data rate, they both can run concurrently on separate cores and can provide ~twice the overall throughput as in-line execution on one thread.  I don't understand what 'blocking issues' are, or why one would wish to avoid them.  What is code supposed to do when it can no longer make forward progress because it must wait for data?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the BlockingQueue and use the Producer/Consumer to illustrate and it proves that it works fine:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(16);
    new Thread(new Producer(queue)).start();
    new Thread(new Consumer(queue)).start();
}

private static class Producer implements Runnable {

    private static final String[] MSGS = {
        "msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4", "msg5",
        "msg6", "msg7", "msg8", "msg9", "msg10"
    };

    final BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        sharedQueue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (String msg : MSGS) {
            try {
                sharedQueue.put(msg);
                // yield the producer thread, so that the consumer could win the CPU
                System.out.println("Produced: " + msg);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Producer was interrupted: " + msg);
            }
        }
    }

}

private static class Consumer implements Runnable {

    final BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        sharedQueue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String toProcess = sharedQueue.take();
                System.out.println("Consumed: " + toProcess);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Consumer was interrupted!");
        }
    }

}
```

So, I think the problem might introduced by the generated message id(what I mean is the e.g., twittermessage1 you've printed out) from you twitterProcessor.